# optimizing searching through memory

Tags: arrays, performance, loops, optimization, linked-list

I have multiple instances of 4096 items. I need to search and find an item on a reocurring basis and i'd like to optimize it. Since not all 4096 items may be used, I thought, an approach to speed things up would be to use a linked list instead of an array. And whenever I have to search an item, once I found it, I'd place it on the head of the list so that next time it comes around, I'd have to do only minimal search (loop) effort. Does this sound right?

**EDIT1**
I don't think the binary search tree idea is really what I can use as I have ordered data, like an array i.e. every node following the previous one is larger which defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

I have attempted to solve my problem with caching and came up with something like this:

```
pending edit
```

But the output I get, suggests that it doesn't work like I'd like it to:

any suggestions on how I can improve this?

Comment: If your arrays or lists of 4096 are ordered (alphabetically or whatever), binary searches are really really fast. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to performance there is only one important rule: measure it!

In your case you could for example have two different considerations, a theoretical runtime analysis and what is really going on one the machine.  Both are heavily depending on the characteristics of your 4096 items. If your data is sorted you can have a O(log n) search, if it is unsorted it is worst case O(n) etc.

Regarding your idea of a linked list you might have more hardware cache misses because the data is not stored together anymore (spatial locality) ending up in having a slower implementation even if your theoretical consideration is right.

If you interested in general in such problems I recommend this cool talk from the GoingNative 2013
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly

Answer (score 1):

Worst case, your search is still O(N) unless you sort the array or list, like Brett suggested.  Therefore with a sorted list, you increase complexity of insertion (to insert ordered), but your searching will be much faster.  What you are suggesting is almost like a "cache."  It's hard for us to say how useful that will be without any idea of how often a found item is searched for again in the near-term.  Clearly there are benefits to caching, it's why we have the whole L1, L2, L3 architecture in memory.  But whether it will work out for you it's unsure.

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** above

Answer (score 1):

Respond to Edit1:
I think if your data element is not large, say, only a few bytes or even tens of bytes, 4096 of them can be fitted into memory. In this case what you need is a hash table. In C++, you use `unordered_map`. For example, you can define `unorderedmap<int, ptr_to_your_node_type>` and get the element in `O(1)` if your key type is `int`.

The fastest search could be `O(1)` if you can design your hash well and the worst case could be `O(n)`. If these items are large and can not be fitted into memory, you can use the so called least recently used cache`algorithm` to save memory.

An example code for LRU cache

```
template <typename K>
class Key_Age{
list<K> key_list;
unordered_map<K, typename list<K> :: iterator> key_pos;
public:
void access(K key){
    key_list.erase(key_pos[key]);
    insert_new(key);
}

void insert_new(K key){
    key_list.push_back(key);
    key_pos[key] = --key_list.end();
}

K pop_oldest(){
    K t = key_list.front();
    key_list.pop_front();
    return t;
}
};

class LRU_Cache{
int capacity;
Key_Age<int> key_age;
unordered_map<int, int> lru_cache;

public:
LRU_Cache(int capacity): capacity(capacity) {
}

int get(int key) {
    if (lru_cache.find(key) != lru_cache.end()) {
        key_age.access(key);
        return lru_cache[key];
    }
    return -1;
}

void set(int key, int value) {
    if (lru_cache.count(key) < 1) {
        if (lru_cache.size() == capacity) {
            int oldest_key = key_age.pop_oldest();
            lru_cache.erase(oldest_key);
        }
        key_age.insert_new(key);
        lru_cache[key] = value;
        return;
    }

    key_age.access(key);
    lru_cache[key] = value;
}
```

};

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** above

Answer (score 1):

If your data can be put in a binary search tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Then you can use a data structure called Splay tree: "A splay tree is a self-adjusting binary search tree with the additional property that recently accessed elements are quick to access again" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree

Comment: please see **EDIT1** above